# Is there a any script to get a Facebook page's name from url with PHP?

Tags: php, facebook

i want to get facebook page name from url with php

```
    if($data!="" and strlen($data) > 10)
    {
        $getFlage   =   0;
        $oHTML      =   str_get_html($data);
        //============================finding form a tag ============================//
        $oA = $oHTML->find('input');
        //print_r($oA);
        if($getFlage==0)

    {
            foreach($oA as $val)

            {
                print 'hello';
                echo $val->href; 
                //print $val->plaintext."<br>";
                $pos = strrpos($val->href, 'facebook.com' );
                if ( $pos > 0 ) 
                {       
                    $graphUrl   =   str_replace("www","graph",$val->input);
                    //echo $graphUrl."<br>";
                    $data   =   array();
                    if (false !== ($contents = @file_get_contents($graphUrl, false, $context))) 
                    {


                            $data = json_decode($contents);
                    }

                    //print "<pre>";
                    if(isset($data->likes))
                    {
                        if($getFlage==0)
                        {
                            $page_name  =   get_page_name($graphUrl);
                            insert_data($data,$Mainval,$page_name);
                            $viaDomain++;
                            $getFlage   =   1;
                            echo "=====get by a tag total like is ".$data->likes."========================<br>";
                        }
                    }

                }

            }
        }
```

i want to get facebook page name from url with php

Comment: Not sure what you're doing here...

Answer (score 0):

You can not get the the name which mean't here the display name you can only get the url name

> e.g: https://www.facebook.com/wonderfull

is a facebook page but its display name is

> Wanda Rachwal

now if you don't the display name just simply the url than u can do it by simply splitting the url string